# How to make my program create a local MYSQL sever in Vb.netLike those provided by xampp?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am making a inventory management software and I want my databse to be hosted on a local MYSQL server I was using xampp for my personal use but I don't want my customer to install xampp or any other similar program I want the sever to be created once my management software runs.(im using vb.net) 
Is this possible?

Comment: everything is possible. it depends how much will/time you want to put into it. Your question is too broad

Comment: I want the sever to be created using my program

Comment: the server gets installed with your app. Then with your app you will be able to create tables and such from run time. To install the database server you need admin rights to create folders in the appropriate location. If your app is running from an account with appropriate security then you should be able to install anything from run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use SQLite - and more accurately it's version System.Data.SQLite directly in your Visual Studio project. here are also NuGet package. The last is System.Data.SQLite 1.0.109.2